# How do I use the cache efficiently when transposing an array?

Tags: c++, caching

If I have a 1D array that represents the contents of an MxN matrix (where the least significant dimension is contiguous in memory), how do I make the best use of caching when transposing it (to place the contents of the most significant dimension in contiguous memory). This question could be rephrased as follows;

**If I have a choice between reading contiguous memory but writing to random access locations or reading from random access locations and writing to contiguous memory, all things being equal, which should I choose?**

Comment: Not in an answer because I haven't actually tested this (interesting question), but if I was going platform-agnostic and had to choose, I would write contiguously. Most have some form of write combining that is probably worth taking advantage of.

Comment: Choose a benchmark .. make sure it's run in an environment suitably close to the final target. This question is really open to a good bit of speculation as it is written, but *if* a benchmark (and representative code) was included, then it might be a good question - that is, the *particular* code and *particular* environment can be looked at.

Comment: @user2864740 ok I didn't realise the question would be so platform/implementation dependant. I will try to update with exact code when I get home (sorry but I'd rather stick my head in the toilet than try to quote code from an iPad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one generally correct approach: code, profile, measure, and compare.

For example: do you need to actually transpose the array? Or could it suffice to read it transposed (in which case an iterator will do the trick). Often times when I interact with my favorite enemy ( Fortran) I have to "read transposed" because the fool is column major.

Play with Eigen, which lets you specify the storage order.

But---again---test and see. It may very we'll be the case that you are pursuing a red herring, and the difference in performance won't make it worth your while to complicate the code.

Comment: Good answer, but I like to understand outcomes before I profile every nook and cranny. Sometimes it's nice to be academic even though it might not be practically significant in every case.

Comment: I am not against being "academic". Quite the opposite. And I also like to understand the "why" of things. That is the reason why, when I doubt, I first measure, then observe, then state a hypotheses, and then try to prove or disprove. It is known that even experts are awful at guessing performance. Always test.

Answer (score 1):

I would chose read contiguous over write contiguous if I have to pick one. Reasons

1. In multi-processor systems when multiple processors are concurrently operating on this data structure, there will be a [cache invalidation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) during writes while cache is much more useful during reads. So in a way cache friendly reads are more beneficial than writes since it can also be shared across processors (or in cases of [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access))
2. Many disks buffers writes at disk controller level and combines writes to disk to maximize throughput so some optimizations there might automatically help in writes.

Of course since there are many assumptions here and depends on your specific use case and hardware so you might have to profile it yourself to see how valid these claims are.

Comment: This was my thinking, until Cory Nelson mentioned write combining to justify the exact opposite answer. Now I'm just confused. I guess profiling is the answer to this question, although I had hoped there would be a relatively platform independent answer to this !

Comment: One more thing to consider would be which operation is done more often reads or writes. You are right, contiguous writes is ideal but if you have to pick one, then you have to give up the other right :). Now among these I picked reads because a cache friendly reads helps all parallel readers, while a cache friendly write helps only the processor writing. All this slowly creeps into micro-optimization domain though.